# Split translation results

Tags: pandas, split, google-colaboratory, multiple-columns, translation

I'm doing traslation of words in csv/excel files here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from googletrans import Translator 
# read from an excel file
df = pd.read_excel('/content/Libro2.xlsx')
translator = Translator()  
df = df.apply(translator.translate,src='en',dest='es').apply(getattr, args=('text',))
```

I get the translation output like this:

[image]

I would like to have this output but I'm not sure what I need to do:

[image]

Comment: Sample input and expected output would help to answer your question

Comment: I added some images about this thanks for let me know that I was not clear at all. @ManjunathKMayya